# Unable to connect to SQL Azure database to webapplication using cloud deployment

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-sql-database

Unable to connect to SQL Azure database to web application using cloud deployment.

In web application `web.config` `<appsettings>` specified as

```
<add key="ConnectionString" 
     value="Server=tcp:n12uejqfps.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DBNAME;User ID=userId;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" />
```

Comment: Unable to connect to AZUR SQL DATABASE  to webapplication using cloud deployment. 

In Web Application web.config appsettings specified as 
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Server=tcp:n12uejqfps.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DBNAME;User ID=userId;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" />

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in your question to address your specific connection error but it appears at first glance like you may have confusion about how to set up the web.config connection strings.

This tutorial on MSDN has a great run-through on setting up your web.config for both local debugging on SQLEXPRESS and cloud configuration for SQL Azure.

[MSDN: Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Cloud Service and SQL Database](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/cloud-service-with-sql-database/)

Comment: Thanks for all, I did mistake in providing database password no problem with connection string